# Does  $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] and $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] always aim to the same directory?

Tags: php, url, webserver, url-routing

Do `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];` and `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` always resolve to the same directory?  Is there a scenario where they wouldn't?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I KNOW these are not the same thing- I'm trying to establish only whether SERVER_NAME will always map to the DOCUMENT_ROOT.  i.e., if by following each of them, one will always arrive at same physical location on the servers file system.

Comment: So, basically, "Are SERVER_NAME and DOCUMENT_ROOT ever different?"

Comment: @Yarin. Just wanted to make you aware of how it looks to others. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SERVER_NAME is internet vieable address - stackoverflow.com
- DOCUMENT_ROOT is absolute URL to current directory - in server /data/stackoverflow/ ...

but yes, it DOES aim to the same directory (everytime)

Comment: I know.  Not asking whether they're different things, just whether they point to the same actual directory.  e.g. Will the publicly accessible file I place at DOCUMENT_ROOT ALWAYS be at SERVER_NAME/file?

Comment: OK- if you update your answer I can give you credit- as is it didnt answer my question

Answer (score 1):

`SERVER_NAME` is not a path it should be the actual domain name. You may want to include `REQUEST_URI` which would give you the absolute path from the perspective of the webserver (assuming you're just using files. REQUEST_URI gives you the path as entered by the user. The webserver or PHP itself can deliver content that isn't even in a file)

For that it really depends on what's in `$some_relative_path`

DOCUMENT_ROOT is the absolute server path to where your web sites files actually live on the server. DOCUMENT_ROOT may be useful for including other PHP files but it should never be exposed to the connecting client as that is a security risk.

They should never be the same in any scenario, unless for some reason someone setup `/` on the server as the document root. That would likely be a very bad idea because then even system files would be exposed to the web.

Comment: @Cfreak- what Im trying to establish is whether they will always point to the same place, not whether they are the same thing.  Generally they do, as the index file served up when navigating to SERVER_NAME will be found in the DOCUMENT_ROOT.  Just trying to find instances when that would not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

SERVER_NAME is the name of the server where the script is been executed. It also could be the virtual host name.

DOCUMENT_ROOT is the path to the script you are executing. If you are running some kind of url rewriting, it could be the same value as SERVER_NAME